# MODE_APPEND flag in shared preferences

Tags: java, android

The `MODE_APPEND` flag gives an error. I don't know why?

I have used `MODE_PRIVATE FLAG` in the on pause activity

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       SharedPreferences sh=getSharedPreferences("MyOwnShared",MODE_APPEND);
       String s1=sh.getString("user","");
       int a1=sh.getInt("age",0);
       name.setText(s1);
       age.setText(String.valueOf(a1));

    }
```

This should run.

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually even if there is an error on that MODE_APPEND constant, the app can run without any problem. So just leave that error and run your app.
I tried to run the app with that error and it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately the OP never clarified what the error actually was (or is) – and also your answer is simply referring to an error. It'd be much more helpful if you could also state the exact error (message) you are referring to.